# Checking if item exists in status bar?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it possible to check whether or not a system item is visible in the status bar on OSX, i.e. the Bluetooth icon?

Has anyone tried doing this before? No mentions on the documentation what so ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths of the active menu bar items are listed in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist`

You can check this way

```
NSURL *userLibraryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
NSURL *systemUIServerPreferences = [userLibraryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist"];
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:systemUIServerPreferences];
BOOL bluetoothIsInMenuBar = [data[@"menuExtras"] containsObject:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu"];

NSLog(@"%d", bluetoothIsInMenuBar);
```

or using `NSPredicate`

```
NSURL *userLibraryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
NSURL *systemUIServerPreferences = [userLibraryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist"];
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:systemUIServerPreferences];
NSPredicate *bluetoothPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains 'Bluetooth'"];
BOOL bluetoothIsInMenuBar = [[data[@"menuExtras"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bluetoothPredicate] count];        

NSLog(@"%d", bluetoothIsInMenuBar);
```